# Is that possible adding the missing file to mount volume when docker container start?

Tags: docker, volume

I have docker image and there is a directory '**A**' which is mount in host directory '**hostA**'.
In directory `**hostA**`, there is a file **file0**.
When I build the docker image, in directy **A**, there is a file **file1**. To be more clear, I show them as below:

```
In host: 
hostA:
   - file0
In docker container: 
A:
   - file1
```

When I start the docker container with the docker image. Since the dir **A** is mounted in host dir `**hostA**` and **hostA** existed when container starting, the **file1** in **A** will not appear although it is build into the docker image. Instead **file0** will be available in dir **A** since it is in **hostA**

My question is whether there is an approach (either during building the docker image or starting the docker container), make the file1 be also available in dir **A** (and in host dir **hostA**).
It means after container starts, it will be

```
In host: 
hostA:
   - file0
   - file1
In docker container: 
A:
   - file0
   - file1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, not as far as I know. As Docker volume mounts are working the same as regular unix mounts, you won't see the file in your Docker container. 
Normally, you separate those directories which will change during the lifetime of your container (like your source code during local development) and those files which don't (e.g. node_modules when working with JavaScript.

I can outline you two ideas which get close to your desired solution and might work for you.

### Mounting to a different directory

You could split your container directory `A` into `AA` and `AB`. `AA` contains the file which were added during build time while `AB` contains files which you're mounting in your container. Then, you can reference the mounted file from the file in your container using relative paths like `../AB/some_file`.

```
# /A/AA/file1.js
require '../AB/file0';
```

```
In host: 
hostA:
   - file0
In docker container: 
A:
  AA:
    - file1
  AB: # mounted
    - file0
```

### Mounting a single file

As another alternative, you can mount a single file. That's a valid solution if you only need to mount a couple of files (like configurations) into your container.

Docker:

```
-v "PWD"/hostA/file0:/A/file0
```

docker-compose:

```
somes_service:
  volumes:
    - hostA/file0:/A/file0
```

Still, the file from your container `file1` won't be available on your host machine.

In that case, you could set the mounted file to be read only, as well.

```
hostA/file0:/A/file0:ro
```

Hope it helps.